# If $A$ is a principal ideal domain, then $_A A$ is uniform

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

An $A-$module $M$ is called a uniform module if the intersection of any two nonzero submodules of $M$ is nonzero.

I don't know how to relate $A$ being a pid with $_AA$ being uniform. Any hint, please?

Answer (score 3):

Any integral domain is uniform as a module over itself.  Uniformity has nothing to do with being a PID.

Very late edit: I'm assuming the rings under consideration are commutative.  A noncommutative domain (i.e., no zero divisors save $0$) can fail to be uniform as a module over itself.  One example is a free algebra in at least two variables.  In this case, $A$ being left Noetherian (for example, being a left principal ideal domain) does help and implies ${}_AA$ is uniform.

Comment: To maybe give a hint as to why being an integral domain is the key property here, given two nonzero ideals $I, J$ of $A$, think about an ideal that $I \cap J$ must contain that uses the multiplication in $A$, and hence allows you to make use of the integral domain property.

Comment: +1 But maybe more precisely "uniformity has nothing to do with being a PIR."